# How Split arrays into two columns With PHP

Tags: php, html, split

i have arrays like :

```
   foreach($Pics AS $Allpics) { 
      print $Allpics;
     }

Result my values: 
 string(40) "760_e7c5c3202c778318fdf92f406da31742.jpg"
 string(40) "760_00f500b6398b4d8a0cde299730f57148.gif"
 string(40) "760_54b1bb6895b636f45c56911be4f67c11.png"
 string(40) "760_05986e1f46651698a8aa4f8ed17ab070.jpg"
```

i need Split array values into two columns !

like :

```
 [column 1]                                            [column 2]

 760_e7c5c3202c778318fdf92f406da31742.jpg             760_54b1bb6895b636f45c56911be4f67c11.png
 760_00f500b6398b4d8a0cde299730f57148.gif             760_05986e1f46651698a8aa4f8ed17ab070.jpg
```

Html Result like :

```
 <div class='row'>

   <div class='col-sm-6'>                                                                         
        760_e7c5c3202c778318fdf92f406da31742.jpg
        760_54b1bb6895b636f45c56911be4f67c11.png
   </div>   

   <div class='col-sm-6'>                                                                             
       760_00f500b6398b4d8a0cde299730f57148.gif
       760_05986e1f46651698a8aa4f8ed17ab070.jpg
   </div>

 </div>
```

thanks for your help my friends!

Comment: why not just use modulus `%` operator?

Comment: How do this......

Comment: Or `array_chunk`

Comment: Those string values, where do you store them. can you collect them and create an array with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do with array_chunk() but the problem is, if records is odd then array_chunk() create third array so, you miss last record.

It's very simple....
Use array_slice() to avoid logical error.

```
$Allpics = array("nature", "trees", "beauty","funny", "fun");

//counting number of records
$countRecords = count($Allpics);

//dividing array in to two array
$col1 = array_slice($Allpics, 0, $countRecords/2 + 0.5);
$col2 = array_slice($Allpics, $countRecords/2 + 0.5, $countRecords);

//making two columns
$row = array("column 1" => $col1, "column 2" => $col2);
print_r($row);
```

//Output

```
Array(
    [column1] => Array(
        [0] => nature
        [1] => trees
        [2] => beauty
    ) [column2] => Array(
        [0] => funny
        [1] => fun
    )
)
```

This code will create two columns, records are odd so, 1st column contain 3 records and 2nd column contain 2 records. If the records are even then it will create two equal columns.

If you want same array keys from $Allpics then use true in array_slice()

Read more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php

Comment: Just use array_chunk by calculating the chunk size using top rounding with ceil. Ex: `$row = array_chunk($Allpics, ceil(count($Allpics) / 2), true);`

Answer (score 1):

use [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
array_chunk($arrays,2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the code, it may help you to achieve your goal

```
$arrays = array('Like' ,'Starts' , 'Moons', 'Skys');
$odd = array();
$even = array();
$i=1;
foreach($arrays as $val)
{
 if($i%2==0)
    $even[] = $val;
 else
    $odd[] = $val; 
 $i++;      
 }
 print_r($odd);
 print_r($even);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array chunks...

```
$arrays = ["Like" ,"Starts" , "Moons", "Skys"];
$arrays = array_chunk($arrays,2);

<div class='row'>
   <div class='col-sm-6'>                                                                         
        <?php foreach ($arrays[0] as $key => $value) {
            echo $value."<br>";
        } ?>
   </div>   
   <div class='col-sm-6'>                                                                             
       <?php foreach ($arrays[1] as $key1 => $value1) {
            echo $value1."<br>";
        } ?>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can specify the column count and the algorithm will do the rest

```
echo "<div class='row'>";

// cant be greater than 12 because bootstrap only supp 12 columns
$columns = 2;
$arrays = array('Like' ,'Starts' , 'Moons', 'Skys');
$array_m = round(count($arrays) / $columns);

for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++){
    echo "<div class='col-sm-".round(12/$columns)."'>";
    for ($i2= $i * $array_m; $i2 < ($i+1==$columns? count($arrays) : $array_m) ; $i2++) { 
        echo $arrays[$i2] . '<br>';
    }
    echo "</div>";
}

echo "</div>";
```

Comment: what do you mean by that @Zandb

Comment: before the arrays i have add foreach for print all my arrays AND result is my arrays have been trimmed !

Comment: Show us what is your variable because from what you told i can tell is not longer an array... is it an String? or what @Zandb

Comment: MY ARRAY VALUE : string(40) "71742.jpg"
string(40) "71745.gif"
string(40) "717411.png"
string(40) "7174245.jpg"

Comment: Can you update your question and post the code you use please

Comment: UPDATED my friend

Comment: @Zandb you need to use `$Pics` variable like `$arrays = $Pics`

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this code
$arrays = array('Like' ,'Stars' , 'Moons', 'Skys');
 $arraychunk=array_chunk($arrays,2);
 ?>
 <div class='row'>
 <?php
     foreach($arraychunk as $item)
     {
        ?><div class='col-sm-6'><?php
        foreach($item as $arr)
         {
            echo "$arr"."<br>"; 
         }  
         ?></div><?php
     }
 ?>
</div>
```